# nodejs loglevel: how can I print out the actual level of the log?

Tags: node.js, logging, express

in [loglevel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loglevel)

`log.debug("test");`

and

`log.error("test");`

will output the same, e.g.

> test
>
> test

What I really want is

> DEBUG: test
>
> ERROR: test

Comment: Have you considered using [Bunyan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan), they have some useful log level stuff described [here](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#levels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loglevel#writing-plugins), You could write a simple plug-in to prefix all log messages with their method name.

```
var originalFactory = log.methodFactory;
log.methodFactory = function (methodName, logLevel, loggerName) {
    var rawMethod = originalFactory(methodName, logLevel, loggerName);

    return function (message) {
        rawMethod(methodName.toUpperCase() + ": " + message);
    };
};

// Be sure to call setLevel method in order to apply plugin
log.setLevel("warn");
```

Comment: btw with this plugin i cannot use any more the style of: `console.log("this is my object: " , {my: "great", obj: "fancy" } );` right ?